# What implication does 臨まれた mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, words

> 同日午後に「退位礼正殿の儀」の実施を告げる「退位礼当日賢所大前の儀」に**臨まれた**。

Source: https://www.sankei.com/life/news/190430/lif1904300016-n1.html

I understand this as, on the same day, there's going to be an announcement of abdication and ＜some other ceremony and　臨まれた＞

I do not understand the part between ＜＞. What does it mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand this as, on the same day, there's going to be an announcement of abdication and ＜some other ceremony and 臨まれた＞

I'm not sure whether you're parsing the sentence correctly...

同日午後に「退位礼正殿の儀」の実施を告げる is a relative clause that modifies 「退位礼当日賢所大前の儀」.

臨ま**れ**た here is the honorific form of 臨んだ. (れる is the honorific auxiliary/尊敬の助動詞.)

> 天皇陛下は３０日午前、［皇祖神の[天照大神]{あまてらすおおみかみ}をまつる］皇居・宮中三殿の[賢所]{かしこどころ}で、［同日午後に「退位礼正殿の儀」の実施を告げる］「退位礼当日賢所大前の儀」に臨まれた。

In the morning of the 30th, at 賢所 in 宮中三殿, the Imperial Palace, ［where the  imperial ancestor 天照大神 is enshrined,］ the Emperor attended 退位礼当日賢所大前の儀, ［where he announced the 実施(holding?) of 退位礼正殿の儀 in the afternoon of the same day.］

Comment: Aha! It was a relative clause. I got confused by the long sentence. I was not parsing it correctly like you said. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

臨む in this context is the following definition from [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/171955/meaning/m0u/%E8%87%A8%E3%82%80/):

> ３ その場所へ出かけていく。特に、公の、または晴れの場所などに、出席または参加する。

It means to participate in/attend a official/public event. The specific event that the Emperor attended is called 退位礼当日賢所大前の儀. From what I can gather it is basically an announcement of his abdication in the 賢所, which is a place in the Imperial Palace.